# Collocation: “teach IN <subject matter>”?

Tags: prepositions, collocations

I would like to know if *to teach "in*" is a valid collocation, as in:

> I teach **in** Computer Science at various Universities.

Comment: I don't think it should be there. It's enough to say *I teach Computer Science* (...)

Comment: @Ale, thanks. But my intention was along the lines of “I teach [various courses] in Computer Science”, wondering if the elision of “various courses” works.

Comment: @dato - Not really, because *you teach courses*, and the courses are *in Computer Science*, but you don't *teach in Computer Science*.

Comment: I think that you don't "need" it there, but, it does give the sentence different implication (ones I've not figured out yet, I don't know if someone could help me out on that or not).

Comment: As a rule this depends on the verb. "I teach Computer Science" is fine but "I work *in* Environmental Sciences." needs the *in*.

Comment: He teaches courses in foreign policy at the University of Somewhere.  He teaches in the _____ department at Somewhere University. He teaches in the _______ Faculty at Somewhere University. He teaches in the Faculty of ____ at Somewhere University.

Comment: @dato the collocation is not with the verb. It's with the noun "a course in CS. Compare this to "a class on geometry".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal feeling is that "Teach in Computer Science" is strange though I would understand the meaning. Let's take a look at what some corpora have to say though.

CoCA (Corpus of contemporary American English) has only one example of "teach in" with a collocation which comes close and that is

"A large proportion of UC faculty teach in science and math subjects or science/math-based professions which are ultimately founded on experiments or their methodological equivalents."

We do have the extra "subjects" but it seems similar to the OP.

All the other collocations described either location ("teach in" university, Africa, London, class, public school), language (English), manner ("teach in a variety of ways") or area in the broad sense ("teach in a field they studied").

Checking the BYU-BNC (british national corpus) no examples similar to the OP were found only examples similar to the ones mentioned above.

Checking Google ngrams neither "teach in computer science" nor "teach in math" was found.

While this is certainly not exhaustive (and my capabilities in working with corpora can easily be questioned) it seems that "teach in " is not used.